# WPF Canvas wont fire DragEnter and Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a canvas that takes items from `ListView` and puts them where the user wants.

Canvas won't fire my DragEnter and Drop events. Here is my code for ListView and Canvas properties.

```
private void itemList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    isDragging = true;
}

private void itemList_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
    Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;

    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
        (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
        Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
    {
        ListView listView = sender as ListView;
        ListViewItem listViewItem =
            FindAncestor<ListViewItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);

        Model.Resource student = (Model.Resource)listView.ItemContainerGenerator.
            ItemFromContainer(listViewItem);

        dragItem = new DDitem(student.getName(), student.getIco());

        DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myFormat", dragItem);

        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listViewItem, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

Now for my `<Canvas>`

```
private static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject
{
    do
    {
        if (current is T)
        {
            return (T)current;
        }
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
    while (current != null);
    return null;
}

private void can_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") || sender == e.Source)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Pokusava drag enter");
}

private void can_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pokusava drop");
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
    {
        Model.Resource student = e.Data.GetData("myFormat") as Model.Resource;
        resources.Remove(student);
        isDragging = false;
    }
}
```

My XAML code for `Canvas` and `ListView` is below

```
<Canvas Name="can"  Background="Transparent" Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.Row="1" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="can_DragEnter" Drop="can_Drop" />
<ListView x:Name="itemList" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="7,23,6,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#324251" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=resources}" FontSize="16" Foreground="Wheat" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="itemList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="itemList_MouseMove"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ico}" Width="70" Height="70"></Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Output gives no exceptions or errors.

Comment: This could sound stupid, but could you please try changing canvas background to anything but not transparent and try again? I remember it happened to me many years ago.

Comment: I have tried with many colors and still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed, the problem was that I've put `Canvas` before `Image`

Now, I've ran to another problem, I'm trying to add my `UserControl` called `DDItem` to canvas, but with no luck. It should follow my mouse pointer and when I release my mouse, it should be put on the canvas. It does get added to my list of dragged items but I cant see it.

XAML code of my `DDItem` is below

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="14*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image x:Name="mask" Source="{Binding Path=src}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Path=name}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Wheat" FontSize="40"/>

</Grid>
```

Code inside my DDItem class

```
public partial class DDitem : UserControl
{
    private string _name;
    private string _path;
    private Point position;
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string path
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DDitem(string name, string path)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
        this.Width = 100;
        this.Height = 100;
        this.DataContext=this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Point getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(Point pos)
    {
        position = pos;
    }
}
```

Now for my Canvas events:

```
private void can_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") || sender == e.Source)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void can_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
        {
            can.Children.Add(dragItem);
            dragItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Canvas.SetTop(dragItem, dragItem.getPosition().Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(dragItem, dragItem.getPosition().X);
            isDragging = false;
            resOnCanvas.Add(dragItem);
        }
    }

    private void can_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragItem != null)
        {
            if (!dragItem.IsVisible)
            {
                dragItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            dragItem.setPosition(e.GetPosition(can));
            Console.WriteLine(dragItem.getPosition().X + " " + dragItem.getPosition().Y);
        }
    }
```